# Dust.js do not add separator after empty values in loop

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I have an array of values, for instance:

```
 {
  "languages": [
    "",
    "CSS",
    "HTML",
    "",
    "JavaScript",
    "Dust",
    "",
    ""
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
CSS, HTML, JavaScript, Dust
```

Is it possible to not add separator after empty values in my dust template without creating custom helper? The problem is that array can have any length with any number of empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only built-in helpers you can write

```
{#languages}
  {@ne key=. value=""}{.}{@sep}, {/sep}{/ne}
{/languages}
```

However, this will leave a dangling comma if the last item in your array is a blank one. If you can find the first non-blank item in your array and pass that data, try this rather-ugly version:

```
{#languages}
  {@ne key=. value=""}{@sep}{@ne key=$idx value=firstNonBlankItem}, {/ne}{/sep}{.}{/ne}
{/languages}
```

If `firstNonBlankItem` is set to the correct index (`1` in your example above), you'll get what you want.

Otherwise, you should really write a custom helper-- that's what Dust intends you to do. You don't even need to include the helper in your context; instead, you could write a custom global helper and include it with your Javascript.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about this approach but I didn't find how to identify "firstNonBlankItem". It seems like writting a helper is the only one solution...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to write a helper? Even if you can't modify your data, you can add a helper to the global `dust.helpers` object very easily.

Comment: You would have to mark `firstNonBlankItem` on the server and include it with your data.

Comment: Yes there is a reason why I didn't want to write it. But looks like I have to do it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your implementation looks like, but could you use CSS content like this? https://jsfiddle.net/fq3ggxqo/

Comment: Thank you! I selected all non empty values in {#languages}{@ne key=. value=""}{.}{/ne}{/languages} and then added separators in CSS like you suggested. Thanks!!